# Confused by Condor baggage policy and weigh-ins

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, condor

My girlfriend and I are flying Condor for the first time next week; it'll be my first international flight, and so I don't know entirely what to expect.  We heard that Condor mostly managed to avoid the nightmares associated with RyanAir, but this problem took us a bit by surprise.

We went Economy Light, underestimating how much they'd charge for baggage and what their actual limits were.  Anyway, we are each allowed to bring 8 kg/17 lbs of stuff, TOTAL.  That's between a carry-on and a personal item.  We're packing light but I still worry we aren't going to be able to make that work, and I'm trying to figure out how and how rigorously this is enforced, and to what extent we can fudge this (cargo pants etc.).  I mean hell, if I fill a Nalgene with water before getting on, that's about a kilogram right there!

I guess the main question is, how and when do they weigh your bag?  I took it to mean they'd have a scale at the gate and weigh everyone's stuff while boarding, my girlfriend thinks that's implausible.  She thought they'd do it when checking in prior to security, but that doesn't make sense to me either; what's to stop you from buying 30 kg of stuff in the airport and cramming it in?  Or is that explicitly permitted? She seemed to think it was.

Checking a 23 kg bag would cost $75 each way and I'd really love to avoid that.

Another bit is about the TOTAL part of it.  It sounds like the 8 kg limit isn't as unusual as I was thinking, but usually that's just for your main carry-on, and not including your "personal item," usually a purse for my girlfriend and a small daypack for me.  Am I correctly interpreting that they'll make us put that on the scale as well?

Comment: If I were you I’d work on it being pretty rigorously enforced; ‘total’ means exactly that, AFAIK. You’re getting a cheaper fare after all. You could try the loading up in the airport approach (done it myself for extra toiletries many times) but only within the carry on bag size limitations, and if your bag ends up being excessively heavy there’s always a risk the crew will pick up on it at boarding. Where are you travelling from/to? Is there an option to buy a smaller baggage package than 23kg?

Comment: Weighing bags right at the gate is definitely not implausible. I've seen it happen on a Ryanair flight years ago, and yes, it was a slow boarding process due to all the measuring (and gate checking). I have no clue what Condor does these days, though...

Comment: So referring to this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101234/condor-carry-on-luggage-check-procedure it looks like if you check-in at arrivals, you weigh your bag there and get an "approved cabin baggage" tag.  Not to say that there's not a risk it wouldn't get spotted, but is that standard after all?  I'm not trying to throw in bowling balls.  Mainly I just don't want to risk filling my water bottle or buying snacks pushing me over the limit.

Comment: @FrankHarris Your water bottle will be empty because you can't take it through security, otherwise.

Comment: Of course!  But I would hope to fill it *after* security, so I might be out of luck just for that, if they weigh it at the gate.